# Duplicate value on data loading

Tags: apex

I wrote a trigger to auto number my aliases, and I'm trying to dataLoad to invoke an update response. I'm getting the error `unknown duplicates value on record with id.`  my dataLoad file does have duplicates, and I not sure how to fix this, and ideas?

Edit --
I do have a unique constrant on SAP_Identifier__c.

Edit -- I have created a new unique number for Alias, I am still getting duplicate ids though

```
 public static void AliasAutoNumber (List<Alias__c> Alias){
    if(Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isAfter){
        Set<id> aliasids = new Set<id>();
        for(Alias__c al: Alias){
            aliasids.add(al.Alias_ID_18_Digit__c);
        }

    if(aliasids.size() > 0){
    //get the largest current auto number
    List<Alias__c > updateThis =new List<Alias__c >();
    Alias__c prevNum = [select SAP_Identifier__c, id from Alias__c where SAP_Identifier__c != null order by SAP_Identifier__c Desc Limit 1];
    List<Alias__c> currNum = [select SAP_Identifier__c, id,Alias_ID_18_Digit__c from Alias__c where Alias_ID_18_Digit__c =:aliasids and SAP_Identifier__c = null];

    if(!aliasids.contains(prevNum.Id)){
    for(Alias__c a: Alias){    
        a.SAP_Identifier__c = prevNum.SAP_Identifier__c +1;
        updateThis.add(a);

    }
}
    try{
        update updateThis;
        }catch(exception e){}
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `for(Alias__c a: Alias)` loop you are repeatedly assigning the `SAP_Identifier__c` to the same value of current_max + 1:

```
a.SAP_Identifier__c = prevNum.SAP_Identifier__c +1;
```

Instead, store that value in its own variable so that it may incremented.

```
Alias__c prevNum = [select SAP_Identifier__c, id from Alias__c where SAP_Identifier__c != null order by SAP_Identifier__c Desc Limit 1];
Decimal maxval = prevNum.SAP_Identifier__c;
```

Then in your loop increment it each time.

```
for(Alias__c a: Alias){    
    a.SAP_Identifier__c = maxval + 1;
    maxval++;
    updateThis.add(a);

}
```